# Java JTextPane is extremely slow when inserting special characters

Tags: java, swing

I found an interesting problem with JTextPane, that it's very slow when I set some texts with special characters to JTextPane.

For example, try the following code ...

```
char c1 = '1';
char c2 = '→';
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++)
        s.append(c1);
JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
textPane.setText(s.toString());
```

When I used c1 to construct the string, it cost about 1 second to set this text to textPane; however, when I used c2 instead, it cost about 5 seconds!!
Well I spent lots of time on finding the reason why my JTextPane.setText() is so slow and eventually found it... Moreover, I tried other special characters like '＊' and it cost about 20 seconds to set the text!!
Anyone knows what is the reason that causes this problem?

Full code snippet:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;    
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Test extends JFrame {
    private JPanel contentPane;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Test frame = new Test();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public Test() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        char c1 = '1';
        char c2 = '→';
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++)
                s.append(c2);
        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        contentPane.add(textPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        textPane.setText(s.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried Oracle Java 7, 8, 9 64bit and Java 8 32bit (all on Win64 platform). In all of the cases setText take around 40ms regardless of whether c1 or c2 is used. Which version of Java are you using? Is the supplied snippet enough to reproduce the effect? I simply inserted it to the main() method.

Comment: I've tried with Oracle Java 8 64bit (on Windows 8.1 64bit). On my laptop `setText` takes around 60 milliseconds and also without much difference between using `c1`, `c2`, or `'＊'`.

Comment: I'm using Oracle Java 8 64bit on Win8.1 64it. The full code snippet is added.

Comment: Now I think I understand your question. When I measure the duration of the `JTextPane.setText` and `s.toString` method calls, I see low values (around 60 milliseconds). What I do notice is a large amount of time (around the 5 and 20 seconds you reported) before the text is actually shown in the GUI. Interesting! What is Swing busy with during that time? Calculating the character width for each of the 1,000,000 identical characters?

Comment: @FreekdeBruijn - possibly.  Possibly attempting to line-wrap or "fill" a ridiculously long character sequence.  You should profile the code.